# SAP HANA - count(*) with condition IN ('1') different from IN (1)

Tags: sql, hana

We are using SAP HANA 1.0 SPS12.

When I run below query-

```
select count(*)
  from ( SELECT A.MATNR ARTICLE,
                A.WERKS SITE, 
                ROUND((SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('551','951') THEN(A.DMBTR) END),0))-SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('552','952') THEN(A.DMBTR) END),0)))) DUMP_VALUE, 
                ROUND((SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('551','951') THEN(A.MENGE) END),0))-SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('552','952') THEN(A.MENGE) END),0)))) DUMP_QTY                   
           FROM MSEG A 
                INNER JOIN S_SITE_MASTER B ON A.WERKS=B.STORE_NO         
                INNER JOIN S_PRODUCT_MASTER C ON A.MATNR=C.MATERIAL                
          WHERE A.BUDAT_MKPF >= ADD_MONTHS(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-1))),-1)
            AND A.BUDAT_MKPF <= ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-1)                       
            AND A.BWART IN ('551','552','951','952')                                       
            AND C.LEVEL2 = 10                                                
            AND B.FORMAT_CD IN ('1')      
       GROUP BY A.MATNR,
                A.WERKS
       );
```

Output count is - 129790

IF I just change clause `AND B.FORMAT_CD IN ('1')` to `AND B.FORMAT_CD IN (1)`, like below -

```
select count(*)
  from (SELECT A.MATNR ARTICLE,
               A.WERKS SITE, 
               ROUND((SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('551','951') THEN(A.DMBTR) END),0))-SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('552','952') THEN(A.DMBTR) END),0)))) DUMP_VALUE, 
               ROUND((SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('551','951') THEN(A.MENGE) END),0))-SUM(COALESCE((CASE WHEN A.BWART IN('552','952') THEN(A.MENGE) END),0)))) DUMP_QTY                   
          FROM MSEG A 
               INNER JOIN S_SITE_MASTER B ON A.WERKS=B.STORE_NO         
               INNER JOIN S_PRODUCT_MASTER C ON A.MATNR=C.MATERIAL                
         WHERE A.BUDAT_MKPF >= ADD_MONTHS(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-1))),-1)
           AND A.BUDAT_MKPF <= ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-1)                       
           AND A.BWART IN ('551','552','951','952')                                       
           AND C.LEVEL2 = 10                                                
           AND B.FORMAT_CD IN (1)      
      GROUP BY A.MATNR,
               A.WERKS
       );
```

Output count - 29403 (which is correct count)

Datatype of B.FORMAT_CD is NVARCHAR(3).

How does count behave differently?

Comment: Could you please help me with any document or note stating that count(*) works differently for different datatypes?

Comment: Sorry I am new to technology. When I run same query on Oracle, I get same result for both the cases. Does Oracle inherently handle this and SAP HANA is doing the same?

Comment: Are you sure that the counts are correctly associated with the two queries.

Comment: yes counts are actual outputs

Answer (score 2):

If `B.FORMAT_CD` is a string, then this is the *right* way to compare values:

```
 B.FORMAT_CD IN ('1')
```

When you do:

```
 B.FORMAT_CD IN (1)
```

Then `B.FORMAT_CD` is converted to a string.  I'm not sure what the values look like, but `'001'` and `'01'` would match in this case.

This explains the difference, but it does not explain why `IN ('1')` would return *more* values than `IN (1)`.

Comment: Good point. Have a look to the data and try B.FORMAT_CD IN ('1', '01', '001') etc.. Would be interesting to see if your counts change.